# How to apply decorator to every Flask view

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

I have a decorator (call it `deco`) that I would like to apply to every view in my Flask app, in order to modify the response headers to avoid IE's compatibility mode (`res.headers.add("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=Edge"`). I use it like

```
@app.route('/')
@deco
def index():
    return 'Hello world'
```

I currently use a subclass of `Flask` to create the app (to modify jinja behavior)

```
class CustomFlask(Flask):
    jinja_options = ...

app = CustomFlask(__name__, ...)
```

Is there a way I can modify `CustomFlask` to apply `deco` decorator to all the responses?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? What is the use case you are trying to solve? This feels like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) if ever I saw one.

Comment: It's for IE. I updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add headers to every outgoing response, use the [`@Flask.after_request` hook](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=after_request#flask.Flask.after_request) instead:

```
@app.after_request
def add_ua_compat(response):
    response.headers['X-UA-Compatible'] = 'IE=Edge'
    return response
```

There is a [Flask extension](https://github.com/jpvanhal/flask-xuacompatible) that does **exactly** this; register the hook and add a header.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Note that as of Flask 0.7 `after_request` may not be called. In this case writing a WSGI middleware may be more appropriate.

Comment: @RobYoung: What makes you think it is not called? I've used this in production with 0.7 without issues. Are you perhaps returning streaming responses?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, maybe Rob thinks of: http://rallion.bitbucket.org/explorations/flask_tutorial/api/flask.Flask.after_request.html

Answer (score 1):

You might consider just writing a custom `WSGI` middleware. You can snag all of your application's responses and augment the headers as necessary. The [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/) discusses how to hook in a middleware and there are no shortage of `WSGI` tutorials on how to add headers to the `start_response`

Comment: I don't see how pluggable views would help here; I'm not sure why the OP thinks decorators would do it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters A decorator may not be necessary, I'm just using it to modify the response headers.

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV: Why not use the [`after_request` hook](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) for that? That's what I use for such a situation.

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV  You might consider rephrasing your question providing details regarding exactly what you want to do with the response.